# How to define range of natural numbers as chars in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, filter

I tried:

```
['1','2',..]
```

but this takes into account other characters also.
I could do [1,2..] , But for my application I need to check the following:

```
  filter (\x -> x `notElem` ['0','1'..]) "a 1 255 d e 6 g h"
```

Which attempts to filter out all elements including spaces that are not natural numbers, in this case 'chars'.

Comment: sounds like [isDigit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit) might be helpful...

Comment: although `['0'..'9']` works fine for this purpose, or even the "longhand" form `"0123456789"`

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? There are only 10 digits ('0' to '9'). Anything bigger than that is not a single character anymore. It doesn't really make sense to talk about the 'range of natural numbers as characters'.

Comment: Please give a full nontrivial test case, what you would want the output to be, and what it currently is instead.

Comment: Id like to account for all natural numbers, including 0

Comment: but you're dealing with them as characters within a string, and *as strings* (assuming decimal notation) all natural numbers are combinations of the 10 characters `'0'` through `'9'`. That's why any of the things I suggested in my first 2 comments should work. Please let me know if I've misunderstood and you don't just want to filter out all digits.

Comment: isDigit works for me. thx everyone. I do check for '0' to '9' indeed

Comment: @Mandy If you've found an answer, can you write up a self-answer and accept it? That way this question won't be listed as unanswered any more.

Comment: `ord 'a'` produces `97`, does that help you? `chr 97` gives `'a'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments there are some ways:

Succession of natural numbers as `chars`. Well as char only numbers from `0` to `9` can be encoded:

```
naturalN :: [Char]
naturalN = ['0'..'9']
```

Example:

```
['0'..'9']

=> "0123456789"
```

As far as a succesion of **all** natural numbers, that cannot be encoded as chars, but as strings. For example:

```
naturalN :: [String]
naturalN = map show [0..]
```

Example:

```
take 20 naturalN
=> ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19"]
```

The problem with this approach is that you cannot check for `elem` or `notElem` because it will never finish to compute if in case the condition is not satisfied since it is an infinite list. You will have to actually use a limit of what you are searching.

Then the problem is how you try to attempt to filter the string, which is ok if you use the first list approach:

```
filter (\x -> x `elem` ['0'..'9']) "a 1 255 d e 6 g h"
=> "12556"
```

Or:

```
filter isDigit "a 1 255 d e 6 g h"
=> "12556"
```

In case you want the oposite, which is take off the numbers of the string:

```
filter (not.isDigit) "a 1 255 d e 6 g h"
=> "a   d e  g h"
```